# How do I save Map<String, List<object>> in sharedPreferences in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

I'm trying to save a `Map<String, List<MyObj>>` in sharedPreferences.
I tried to use the classic `sharedPreferences` package, but I'm having trouble.
If I save a string to sharedPreferences, then when I try to retrieve and use `json.decode(...)`,
I get the error `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)...`
If I try to save it using `json.encode(...)`, I get the error `Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MyObj'`.
What I'm trying to save is like this:

```
{ExampleString: [Instance of 'MyObj', Instance of 'MyObj'...], ExampleString2: [Instance of 'MyObj', Instance of 'MyObj'...], ...}
```

How can I solve this?
Is there a package that allows you to save map?

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom object:

```
class User {
  String name;
  String age;
  String location;

  User();
}
```

Create toJson and fromJson:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  'name': name,
  'age': age,
  'location': location,
};

User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : name = json['name'],
      age = json['age'],
      location = json['location'];
```

Then save it like this:

```
prefs.setString(key, json.encode(value));
```

Load it like this:

```
json.decode(prefs.getString(key));
```

Comment: perfect, seems it's working, the toJson() method were missing, but now i receive the error Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<MyObj>>'